# Generic way to control disabled in windows form

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a form item (in this case a radio button) to toggle being disabled on a double click. by default I want the item to be disabled (this part works) however I cannot seem to get my javascript function to change the status of disabled for the ondblclick="".
Its also worth noting that I wan t to reuse this function on many different form items. So its important that I keep it generic so it can be reused, simply by calling the function.

Here is my form's radio button's code:

```
<input type="radio" name="clubMember" id="member" value="Member" <?= $U_Club_Member == "Member" ? 'checked' : '' ?>  onMouseDown="this._chckd = this.checked" onclick=" if (this._chckd) this.checked = false;  return validateClubInfo();" ondblclick="return disableToggle();" disabled = "true" />Club Member
<input type="radio" name="clubMember" id="nonMember" value="Non-Member" <?= $U_Club_Member == "Non-Member" ? 'checked' : '' ?> onMouseDown="this._chckd = this.checked; this._dsbld = this.disabled" onclick="if (this._chckd) this.checked = false; return validateClubInfo();" ondblclick="return disableToggle();" disabled = "true"  />Non Member
```

Here is my javascript function:

```
function disableToggle()
        {
            if(this.disabled == true)
            {
                this.disabled = false;
                return true;
            }
            else if(this.disabled == false)
            {
                this.disabled = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Disabled elements do not respond to click events.

Comment: Is there a way to get around that? I want things to be disabled until users double click on them. or is this impossible?

Comment: @Diodeus Yes they do. I think... damnit, now I have to go check!

Comment: Place an invisible div over the disabled item and hook up the click event to it instead.

Comment: Diodeus I will try it with a div, that may actually be more beneficial in the long run. Does my toggle function posted above need to be changed for that or is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't passing the context to the `disableToggle` function, it is trying to disable the entire window.

Try this: `ondblclick="disableToggle(this);"`
And this: `function disableToggle(radio) {radio.disabled = !radio.disabled;}`

Or even this: `ondblclick="this.disabled = !this.disabled;"`

---

Okay, scrap the above. The event won't fire on disabled elements.

But ask yourself if this is really a good idea. I mean, how will the user know to double-click. What if the user CAN'T double-click (ie. touchscreens/phones... or people who just use their keyboard like me)